# determining whether a turing machine

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

For $i\in \mathbb{N}$, define $L_i :=${$ ⟨M⟩ |$ On input $101$ M halts after at most i steps}

For any fixed i the language $L_i$ is decidable as if there is no end state up to the i$^{th}$ position on the tape of the turing machine then $L$ doesn't terminate.

However i have been asked to Use Rice’s theorem to prove that $L = \cup$ $L_i$ with $i \in \mathbb{N}$ is undecidable.

How would i do this? could I compose the tapes and which would never halt as it would be the sum of the natural numbers?

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** $L=\bigcup L_i$ is the set of all programs that halt on input `101` after _any_ number of steps. This means in particular that $L$ is extensional.

Comment: could i then say that this is equivalent to the halting problem which we know to be undecidable? @HenningMakholm if do then this makes sense but then how would rices theorem actually be used

Comment: x @PeterA; It is true that the problem is equivalent to the halting problem, and you _could_ easily prove it undecidable by the diagonalization argument that works for the ordinary halting problem. However, if the exercise asks you to use Rice's theorem instead, you should do that: (1) Find the statement of Rice's theorem; it says that set of programs that satisfies such-and-such conditions is necessarily undecidable. (2) Prove that your $L$ satisfies the conditions from the theorem. (3) You're done!